# How to run apt-cacher-ng behind a proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, apt-cache

I can not find, in the `apt-cacher-ng` [documentation](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/index.html), how to configure the proxy settings.

Is it possible to run `apt-cacher-ng` behind a proxy? How?

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following to `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf`:

```
Proxy: http://myproxy.net:1234
```

As described in [this sample config file](https://github.com/Efreak/apt-cacher-ng/blob/master/conf/acng.conf):

```
# The specification of another HTTP proxy which shall be used for downloads.
# It can include user name and password but see the manual for limitations.
#
# Default: uses direct connection
#
# Proxy: http://www-proxy.example.net:3128
# Proxy: https://username:proxypassword@proxy.example.net:3129
```